# Slow animation when edit bootstrap column

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

in a page with Bootstrap after resizing a column I would like the columns to be reset in "slow" mode.
I have a site built this way:

- A: `col-md-2`
- B: `col-md-10`
- C: `col-md-10`
- D: `col-md-7` (child of C)
- E: `col-md-3` (child of C)

[image]

When start my event B width becomes like E

[image]

And use:

```
$("B").detach().prependTo("C");
```

[image]

Now the div "D" takes you to the top of the page very quickly
[image]

I did not find any way to slow down this last step. Can you help me?

Comment: and your code ?

Comment: Can you provide a code sample so we can recreate the example provided?

Comment: add code snippet so that we can edit your code.

Answer (score 1):

so i tried to produce this in a fiddle since it's a small simple layout

First of all if you `detach` the B and append it to the C directly, you'll have two problems :

- the B still have `col-md-10` so it won't have the same width as the E and you need to change that before the `append`
- `AppendTo` adds the element ( B ) to the end of the div ( C ) so it will be placed under the two others ( D and E ) and you won't have the desired results

so :

- use `prependTo` instead of `appendTo` to have the element added to the begining ( http://api.jquery.com/prependto/ )
- change the `width` of the B to be the same as the E
- `float : right` the B

and for the `animation` part :

you can add `margin-right: 1px` to the B to prevent the D from coming up right away
then animate the D to the top
and when it's all done, reset the values of B's `margin` and D's `top`

like so :

```
var bHeight = $('#b').height(); // keep the height of the B to use it when animating the D to the top

   $('#b').detach().prependTo('#c').css({
        'width' : '33.33%', // same as E
        'margin-right': '1px' // to prevent D from coming up right away         
    });

    $('#d').animate({
        top : - bHeight + 'px' // move the D to the top
    }, 500, function(){
        // reset teh values
        // if you had theses values before, keep them in variables and reset them here
        $('#b').css({'margin-right' : 0});
        $('#d').css({top : 0});
    });
```

here's a fiddle to play around with : https://jsfiddle.net/1uaw304o/54/

```js
setTimeout(function(){
 
    var bHeight = $('#b').height(); // keep the height of the B to use it when animating the D to the top
    
   $('#b').detach().prependTo('#c').css({
     'width' : '33.33%', // same as E
     'margin-right': '1px' // to prevent D from coming up right away         
    });
    
    $('#d').animate({
     top : - bHeight + 'px' // move the D to the top
    }, 500, function(){
      // reset teh values
        // if you had theses values before, keep them in variables and reset them here
     $('#b').css({'margin-right' : 0});
        $('#d').css({top : 0});
    });
   
}, 500);
```

```css
div{
    padding: 0;
}
#a{
    background: red;
    height: 300px;
}
#b{
    background: blue;
    height: 150px;
    float: right;
}
#c{
    background: gray;    
    padding: 0;
}
#d{
    background: lightblue;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
#e{
    background: yellow;
    height: 150px;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-2" id="a">
A
</div>
<div class="col-xs-10" id="b">
B
</div>
<div class="col-xs-10" id="c">
    <div class="col-xs-8" id="d">
    D
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4" id="e">
    E
    </div>
</div>
```

i hope this helps or at least gives you an idea on where to go, but please next time you post a question consider providing your code or at least a jsFiddle with an example so you can get precise answers .

Comment: hello, i notices that you changed your mind about accepting the answer and i'm wondering why ..